# Report Viewer data not displayed out after change start date

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

Previously, all reports were working fine until today. Today was the day for the deployment. If i changed the end date or the other parameters, it works well. But when i changed the start date, the result will not appear anymore as shown in the image[image]

Comment: What datatype are the date parameters? I don't see the date picker image.

Comment: Already solved the issue due to ajax dll problem